# Consider a function $f(x, y)$ and an ODE $\frac{dy}{dt} = g(x)$, does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ hold $y$ constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, intuition

**Consider a function $f(x, y)$ and an ODE $\frac{dy}{dt} = g(x)$, does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ hold $y$ constant?**

Two thoughts:

- Potentially, the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ holds all variables other than $x$ constant, so $y$ remains constant,
- or, with $\int dy = \int \frac{dy}{dt} dt = \int g(x) dt$, y depends on $x$ so I need to somehow apply the chain rule, and $y$ is not held constant? How does $\frac{dy}{dt}$ appear in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ in this case?

**What is actually correct?**

### Context

I want to understand partial derivatives. Quoting directly from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative), "a partial derivative of a function of several variables is its derivative with respect to one of those variables, with the others held constant."

Now I am wondering what exactly "the others held constant" means.

### Related

The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221621/consider-a-function-fx-y-zx-v-does-frac-partial-f-partial-z-hold) discusses a similar issue, but I am not sure if the reasoning provided there also applies to variables changing as described by an ODE.